# Accessing passed parameters of PyQt5 QChartView inside of overrided class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to use PyQt5 QtChart module to plot multiple charts on two different tab widgets with custom mouse and key events to zoom in and out from the charts.

So I created another class to override the QChartView class events like follows:

```
class my_view(QChartView):
    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Plus:
            ex.my_chart.zoomIn()            # ex.chart is accessed from outside
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Minus:     # self.passed_parameter would be the solution
            ex.my_chart.zoomOut()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        ...

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        ...

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ...
```

and in the class Window is the call to my_view:

```
self.my_chart = QChart()
self.my_chart_view = my_view(self.my_chart, self.parent)
```

There is the call of the Window class from which the chart can be accessed outside the window class:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Window()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

The problem came out when I created two instances of my_view like this:

```
self.my_chart = QChart()
self.my_chart_view = my_view(self.my_chart, self.parent) 
self.my_chart1 = QChart()
self.my_chart1_view = my_view(self.my_chart1, self.parent1)
```

and if I zoomed the second one, the first one was zoomed on the other tab...

So my question is, how can I access self.my_chart from inside the overrided class if I don't know how it is named inside the class?

Comment: Why not just `self.chart().zoomIn()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ekhumoro stated in his comment, the solution was

```
self.chart().zoomIn()
```